# Django: integration of external classes?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I apologise in advance for the silly question. :)

I am trying to create a REST API using the Django rest-framework. This API sits on top of an algorithm, which I have been trying to integrate within the Django framework, but it is frustrating to do this properly, and I suspect this is due to my poor understanding of Django.

Here are my code snippets.

models.py

```
from django.db import models                                                                         

class my_model(models.Model):
  dob = models.TextField()
  response = models.TextField()
  field1 = models.TextField()

class Meta:
  ordering = ('dob','response','field1')
```

serializers.py

```
import re
import numpy as np
from django_rest.quickstart.models import my_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from my_algorithm import my_algorithm

class myAlgorithmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  my_algorithm_instance = my_algorithm()
  response = serializers.SerializerMethodField('myAlgorithm_wrapper',my_algorithm_instance)
  field1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('field1_wrapper', my_algorithm_instance)

  def myAlgorithm_wrapper(self, my_model, my_algorithm_instance):

    # Get the inputs.                                                                                                                                                                                   
    dob = str(my_model.dob)

    components = np.array(re.split('/| |:', dob)).astype(int)

    birth_day = components[0]
    birth_month = components[1]
    birth_year = components[2]
    birth_hour = components[3]
    birth_minutes = components[4]

    my_algorithm_instance.set_birthdate_time(\
                birth_year, birth_month, birth_day,\
                birth_hour, birth_minutes)

    my_algorithm_instance.run()

    my_structure = my_algorithm_instance.my_struct
    content = JSONRenderer().render(my_structure)

    return(content)

  def field1_wrapper(self, my_model, my_algorithm_instance):
    another_structure = my_algorithm_instance.another_pillar_struct
    content = JSONRenderer().render(another_structure)
    return(content)

  class Meta:
    model = Bazhi
    fields = ('dob', 'response', 'field1')
```

I get an error message, which essentially says that the methods 'myAlgorithm_wrapper' and 'field1_wrapper' only accepts 2 arguments, and not the required 3. My algorithm instance is required in both wrappers, but even though they should be within scope of those methods, they are reported as 'missing'. Stack trace below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm_app/myAlgorithm/django_rest/urls.py", line 29, in <module>
    from django_rest.quickstart import views
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm_app/myAlgorithm/django_rest/quickstart/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django_rest.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer, myAlgorithmSerializer
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm_app/myAlgorithm/django_rest/quickstart/serializers.py", line 25, in <module>
    class myAlgorithmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  File "/home/pi/myAlgorithm_app/myAlgorithm/django_rest/quickstart/serializers.py", line 27, in myAlgorithmSerializer
    response = serializers.SerializerMethodField('myAlgorithm_wrapper', my_algorithm_instance)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Should I be incorporating this in models.py instead using a manager? The documentation doesn't seem to include a way to retrieve a certain field - dob in my case, and process it. Even if this method is plausible, would I run into trouble with scoping as in the serializer? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks very much!
Ed

Comment: You haven't really given enough information. What is `my_algorithm`? Why are you instantiating it at class level in the serializer? And most importantly, what were you doing when you got those errors? Where are the full error tracebacks?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. 'my_algorithm.py' is a custom python class that takes in the date of birth and does some calculations based on that. I have now appended a stack trace to the post. More specifically, when the client does a POST with data containing the date of birth, my_algorithm should be invoked to process it and return a few output fields, 'response' and 'field1'. Where do you suggest would be a more apt place to instantiate it? Some code based examples will be useful. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything at all to do with your external classes. As the traceback shows, the issue is to do with the arguments to SerializerMethodField. Like all serializer fields, to should use keyword arguments, not positional arguments; and the main keyword arg to that field is [`method_name`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by passing the algorithm instance into the field. Even if that worked, the docs also state that the methods referenced from this field should have a single argument, the object being serialized. If the idea is that the algorithm instance is something that is shared by both methods, then perhaps you should instantiate it in the `__init__` method of the serializer and then just reference it in the methods:

```
class myAlgorithmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  response = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='myAlgorithm_wrapper')
  field1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='field1_wrapper')

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.my_algorithm_instance = my_algorithm()
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def myAlgorithm_wrapper(self, my_model):
     ...
     # refer to self.my_algorithm_instance
     ...
```